# Understanding definition of a Limit Point (Very quick clarification question)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Quick Question/
Slight confusion I am having:
If I know for sure that a point x is not a limit point of a set, A, does this necessarily imply that x is not an element or member of the set A.  I drew a picture to try and understand this.  Thank you.

Actually.  I think I am wrong, a point can be a member of a set and not a limit point, then it would be isolated.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you define a limit point of a set. Normally you define it like here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

In that sense, you are totally right. An isolated point is no limit point of a set by definition of an isolated point.

If you compare the definition of a limit point and an isolated point of a set $A$, you see that each point is either a limit point xor an isolated point of $A$.